# Running NUnit against .Net 4.0 NHibernate over SQLite cannot load SQLite DLL

Tags: nhibernate, sqlite, .net-4.0, fluent-nhibernate, nunit

I know this is a "duplicate", but the answers on all the other posts are not working for me.
My error message is also slightly different.

No matter what I try I cannot get SQLite to to run. I have tried every thing I could find on the net/stackoverflow and every set of SQLite DLLs.

I have tried:

```
<runtime>
    <loadFromRemoteSources enabled="true" />
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Data" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089"/>
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="2.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0"/>
        </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

I also have tried both safe and unsafe versions of the DLLs.
NUnit.exe will pass the test, but running them with TestDriven.Net in visual studio does not work.

Full stack trace when fluent nhibernate runs the configuration:

```
SetUp : FluentNHibernate.Cfg.FluentConfigurationException : An invalid or incomplete configuration was used while creating a SessionFactory. Check PotentialReasons collection, and InnerException for more detail.
  ----> System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException : Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture.  Make sure "System.Data.SQLite.SR.resources" was correctly embedded or linked into assembly "System.Data.SQLite" at compile time, or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed.
  d:\Builds\FluentNH-v1.x-nh3\src\FluentNHibernate\Cfg\FluentConfiguration.cs(232, 0) : FluentNHibernate.Cfg.FluentConfiguration.BuildSessionFactory()
  C:\inetpub\wwwroot\TrunkB\Company.Tests\BaseNHibernateTest.cs(50, 0) : Company.Tests.BaseSQLiteNHibernateTest.<SetUp>b__1(IInitializationExpression x)
  C:\inetpub\wwwroot\TrunkB\Company.Tests\BaseNHibernateTest.cs(36, 0) : Company.Tests.BaseSQLiteNHibernateTest.SetUp()
  d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Dialect\Schema\AbstractDataBaseSchema.cs(97, 0) : NHibernate.Dialect.Schema.AbstractDataBaseSchema.GetReservedWords()
  d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Tool\hbm2ddl\SchemaMetadataUpdater.cs(47, 0) : NHibernate.Tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaMetadataUpdater.GetReservedWords(Dialect dialect, IConnectionHelper connectionHelper)
  d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Tool\hbm2ddl\SchemaMetadataUpdater.cs(17, 0) : NHibernate.Tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaMetadataUpdater.Update(ISessionFactory sessionFactory)
  d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Impl\SessionFactoryImpl.cs(169, 0) : NHibernate.Impl.SessionFactoryImpl..ctor(Configuration cfg, IMapping mapping, Settings settings, EventListeners listeners)
  d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Cfg\Configuration.cs(1246, 0) : NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.BuildSessionFactory()
  d:\Builds\FluentNH-v1.x-nh3\src\FluentNHibernate\Cfg\FluentConfiguration.cs(227, 0) : FluentNHibernate.Cfg.FluentConfiguration.BuildSessionFactory()
```

I am also getting this error now:

```
Company.Tests.Infrastructure.TruckRepositoryTests.CanLoadTrucksByUserIdFilter:
SetUp : System.BadImageFormatException : Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SQLite, Version=1.0.66.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
```

Comment: figured it out. just dont know how to close the issue.

Comment: i switched to the ado.net version from source forge instead of system.data.sqlite.org

Comment: http://www.csharpcity.com/mixed-assembly-mode-error-with-net-4-0-sqlite-nunit-and-partcover/

Comment: I take that back. This did not work. Only thought it was working. Still having this issue. =(

Comment: Brad, have you tried my suggestion?

Comment: I updated my answer, apparently there is also an option in TestDriven.NET to run tests in 32 bit or 64 bit.

Comment: I am now using SQLite 32-bit because that is the only one that would run with coderush. I did not test testdriven.net in 64-bit mode. And the other fix was to use the 32-bit version of nunit for the continuous integration server. Your answer lead me to the correct solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
System.BadImageFormatException
```

This most likely means that you are trying to load a 32-bit assembly into a 64-bit process or vice versa. I imagine that you are running a 64-bit operating system. In this case the program will run as a 64-bit process if Any CPU configuration is selected. One of NUnit and Testdriven.NET might be running as 32-bit and the other 64-bit which will explain why one works and the other doesn't.

Make sure that you are using the correct version of Sqlite (32 bit or 64 bit) when running with a 32/64 bit process.

**UPDATE**: There is an option for TestDriven.NET for it use 32-bit or 64-bit processes. Go to Tools -> Options -> TestDriven.NET and change ANY CPU tests to use 64-bit instead.

Comment: I setup everything to use the 32 bit DLL and am using NUnit-x86.exe to run the tests. This works. I guess when Visual Studio/testdriven/coderush runs 64bit I can use the 64 bit nunit.

Answer (score 3):

I have this problem using fluent nhibernate and automappings with sqlite, in a .net framework 4 solution, i checked in the new system.data.sqlite site and it's a problem related with the resources inside the library, they already fixed but not it's not a release soon.

The link with the checkin:
[Checkin info in system.data.sqlite repository](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/ci/55f56ce508)

I downloaded the source code i compiled myself, and it's working now with the automapper in fluent nhibernate, maybe can work for you meanwhile the people of system.data.sqlite relase a new version:

[Compiled source code of 1.0.74.0 version with the fix](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/11743464/System.Data.SQLite%201.0.74.0.rar)